# Override accepted renderer in django-rest-framework on exception

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to create an endpoint which returns a PDF. However, when there is an error rendering the PDF, I want to return a JSON response. But DRF passes the data for the exception to my PDFRenderer class. How can I use JSONRenderer instead, only if there is an error?

```
class PDFRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    """ DRF renderer for PDF binary content. """
    media_type = 'application/pdf'
    format = 'pdf'
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return bytes(data)
```

For example, when my view says [`raise PermissionDenied()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#permissiondenied), because the authorized user does not have permission to view the requested PDF, DRF passes `{'detail': 'You do not have permission to perform this action.'}` as the `data` argument to `PDFRenderer.render`.

**Edit:** I tried a [custom exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) but apparently you still have to run it through DRF's exception handler as well, which passes it to the PDFRenderer.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to do this with a custom exception handler after all:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    """ Switch from PDFRenderer to JSONRenderer for exceptions """
    if context['request'].accepted_renderer.format == 'pdf':
        context['request'].accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
    return exception_handler(exc, context)
```

It feels pretty hacky. Still hoping for a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

If request is ok and file exists, I read it as bytes and pass it to Response, as custom renderer I use PDFRenderer as yours. If request isn't ok, I return json. My solution is to check if data is instance of bytes, if not, I just return bytes from valid json string, because render method should return bytes anyway

```
class PDFRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/pdf'
    format = 'pdf'
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if isinstance(data, bytes):
            return data
        data_to_response = json.dumps(data)
        return bytes(data_to_response.encode('utf-8'))
```